# How to prevent displaying information on phone while Android Auto is active?

Tags: android, android-auto

There is a test `Google Play Store team` does when they review `Android Auto` apps which forbids the visual information presented by the app on the phone while the app is active on `Android Auto`.

What is the best way to pass this test? Shall I just overlay a black screen which has a `TextView` on it saying "Android Auto Mode is ON"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t any need to write in an additional overlay for this, It’s handled by Android Auto for you.  This will be automatically applied when running while attached to a vehicles Head Unit.

Here’s the link to documentation on [Testing apps for Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing) for  more info (just in case). While i’m connected to the DHU with a simple sample app, this is a screenshot of the what is visible from the mobile device.

[image: Sample app while connected to DHU screen cap]

Submitting your app to the Beta or Alpha channels will also kick off a review. If there’s anything that needs to be corrected or updated, you’ll receive an email with more information about what actions you’ll need to take.

Comment: I found out that I was launching an activity when a certain command is called from android auto methods, I prevented that and it solved the problem.